# How Do I add JavaScript to html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript from codeacademy & I want to put a sample javascript into a html document. How would I go about this? This is the javascript:

```
var myName = "Codecademy";
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

drawName(myName, letterColors);

if(10 < 3)
{
    bubbleShape = 'square';
}
else
{
    bubbleShape = 'circle';
}

    bounceBubbles();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do that. But there is only one way to do it "right".
The first one is putting your javascript code into the head section of your html, like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // your code here
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a good way, but not the best (later I explain why). Now let's see other way, not the best yet:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // your code here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine but don't recommended.

The third and best way to do it:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/js/file.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can load directly your javascript code from an external file and this is the best way because you have your code ordered, with sense and separately. The javascript code is read from top to bottom, like html. The second way is used, generally, to affect elements above already painted on the view. But you can do the same at three ways. The best? The cleanest and ordered way.

Comment: Thank you for all the methods

Comment: Is the path to the javascript correct? View your source code in navigator and make sure that it is loaded. In addition, you have nice utilities like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to test your frontend code

Comment: I will have to remember that link. The path was incorrect, its alright now

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your code inside a `<script>` element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//your code here
</script>
```

[**Manual**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Answer (score 0):

You use the `<script>` tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var myName = "Codecademy";
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

drawName(myName, letterColors);

if(10 < 3)
{
    bubbleShape = 'square';
}
else
{
    bubbleShape = 'circle';
}

    bounceBubbles();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Put your HTML codes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in script tags, at the bottom of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //put script in here
</script>
```

Comment: If the script references DOM elements, this ensures that they exist, so you don't need to wrap it in a `window.onload` function.

Comment: Sorry - I should have clarified. Yes - ensures the page is loaded and then runs the script. It's habit from the way I write / use code.

Comment: I use the document.ready function, as per design recommendations from JQuery and Google... Seems legit to me.

Comment: @simonadcock  because, that I said in my post, the code should be ordered, clean and with sense. All ways are accepted anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<script>
var myName = "Codecademy";
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

drawName(myName, letterColors);

if(10 < 3)
{
    bubbleShape = 'square';
}
else
{
    bubbleShape = 'circle';
}

    bounceBubbles();
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline scripts can go in the head section of an html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myName = "Codecademy";
            var red = [0, 100, 63];
            var orange = [40, 100, 60];
            var green = [75, 100, 40];
            var blue = [196, 77, 55];
            var purple = [280, 50, 60];
            var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

            drawName(myName, letterColors);

            if(10 < 3)
            {
                bubbleShape = 'square';
            }
            else
            {
                bubbleShape = 'circle';
            }

            bounceBubbles();
       </script>
</head>
<body>
    Body content goes here...
</body>
```

Wrap it in `<script>` tags. The `type` attribute is optional in HTML5.